# Tensorflow Model is not restoring without context manager

Tags: tensorflow

I've a trained model which I've named it as `best_model`.

So in my current working directory I have:

- `best_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`
- `best_model.ckpt.index`
- `best_model.ckpt.meta`
- `checkpoint`

Now if I try to load by the following snippet, it loads and gives result perfectly.

```
checkpoint = "./best_model.ckpt"

loaded_graph = train_graph
with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
    # Load saved model
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)

    # some code for inference
```

What if I want to do inference multiple times. I don't want to load the model each and every time. So I decided to put the inference code in a function and I'm loading the model separately.

But the following snippet doesn't work

```
checkpoint = "./best_model.ckpt"

loaded_graph = train_graph
sess = tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph)
loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)

def inference(text):
    # some code
```

The following is the Traceback

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./best_model.ckpt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-1947eb6ae173> in <module>()
     12 checkpoint = "./best_model.ckpt"
     13 loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint + '.meta')
---> 14 loader.restore(sess, checkpoint)
     15 
     16 #sess = gen_sess()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py in restore(self, sess, save_path)
   1455     logging.info("Restoring parameters from %s", save_path)
   1456     sess.run(self.saver_def.restore_op_name,
-> 1457              {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
   1458 
   1459   @staticmethod

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    914       raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
    915     if self.graph.version == 0:
--> 916       raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
    917                          'graph before calling run().')
    918 

RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

I'm using `tensorflow 1.1.0`, because I'm using an old github code for trying purposes. I'm new to tensorflow and I don't know if I'm missing some obvious concepts. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you pass a new session, `sess = tf.Session()`, to `loader.restore`?

Comment: thanks @dpk It's working now. Can you tell what was the reason for not working ?

Comment: In `loaded_graph = train_graph`, where is `train_graph` defined?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that, that is defined before this while creating the graph, but why your suggestion worked ?

Comment: I need to know how you defined it.

Comment: https://github.com/Currie32/Text-Summarization-with-Amazon-Reviews/blob/master/summarize_reviews.py - this one